# haskell AD module: difficulties with Mode typeclass

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and having a hard time understanding how to get my program using the automatic differentiation module AD to typecheck.

My goal is to implement an implicit Euler ODE solver which makes use of newton's method to numerically solve the discretized equation. (I am trying to generalize this to systems of ODEs, but for my question it is sufficient to consider the case of only one ODE)

I have implemented the newton method as follows:

```
import Numeric.AD
import Numeric.AD.Rank1.Forward (Forward, diff')

newton :: (Fractional a, Eq a, Ord a) => (Forward a -> Forward a) -> a -> a -> a
newton equation guess tolerance
    | abs (equation (auto guess)) < auto tolerance = guess
    | otherwise = newton equation newGuess tolerance
    where
        newGuess = guess - correction
        (y,y') = diff' equation guess
        correction = y/y'
```

This function works, in the sense that I can use it in something like

```
mySqrtOfTwo = newton (\(x) -> x^2 - 2) 1 0.001
```

However, if I try to use it in another function, such as

```
impEuler f (x, y) newx = (newx, newy) 
    where
        newy = newton fDisc y 1e-3
        fDisc yUnknown = yUnknown - y + (newx - x) * (f (x,yUnknown))
```

I get the error

```
• Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b ~ Forward b
• In the second argument of ‘newton’, namely ‘y’
      In the expression: newton fDisc y 1e-3
      In an equation for ‘newy’: newy = newton fDisc y 1e-3
```

I think I understand why this error appears, but I do not understand why it only occurs when the `newton` function is used in another function and not when it is called directly. Moreover, I am wondering what the proper way to deal with this is.

I have thought about implementing the function `newton` slightly differently, in such a way that it has the type

```
newton :: (Fractional a, Eq a, Ord a) => (a -> a) -> a -> a -> a
```

but I do not know how to do this and if this is even good style.

To simplify the question: I know that I can use `auto` to go from `a` to `Forward a`, but I don't know how to go the other way and if this is even possible.

EDIT: as @leftroundabout suggested, I implemented the function as follows:

```
impEuler :: (Double -> Forward Double -> Forward Double) -> (Double,Double) -> Double -> Double
impEuler f (x, y) newx = newy
where newy = newton fDisc y 1e-3
      fDisc :: Forward Double -> Forward Double
      fDisc yUnknown = yUnknown - realToFrac y - realToFrac (newx - x) * f x yUnknown
```

This requires the ode passed to impEuler to also have the type `(Double -> Forward Double -> Forward Double)`, which I wanted avoid because I might decide to solve the ode with an explicit method (which does not require newton's method). Therefore, I added the function

```
odePromoter :: (Double -> Double -> Double) -> (Double -> Forward Double -> Forward Double)
odePromoter ode x y = realToFrac (ode x (realToFrac y))
```

in order to turn an ode of type (Double -> Double -> Double) into one of type (Double -> Forward Double -> Forward Double).

Comment: Just so you know, "new to Haskell" and "trying to use the `ad` package" together suggest that you're quite ambitious! What is the intended type of `impEuler`? Style point: it's pretty strange for a function to return a pair one of whose components is an argument to the function; normally you'd return just the new information and let the caller pack it up as needed.

Comment: I see, good to know that this is acutally an advanced topic ^^ I got the idea for the type of impEuler from [this blog](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2016/06/02/ode-solver-as-a-functional-fold/), the idea being that one can perform the ode integration using `scanl (impEulerSystem odeSystem) ((head etaValues) ,initialConditions) (tail etaValues)
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crucial thing is, `fDisc` must be able to support the automatic differentiation. I.e. it must have a type like `Forward Double -> Forward Double`. However, in

```
   fDisc yUnknown = yUnknown - y + (newx - x) * (f (x,yUnknown))
```

you have the values `y`, `x` and `newx`, and these are plain concrete-numbers, probably `Double`. Haskell never converts / promotes types implicitly, so with that you demand that `fDisc :: Double -> Double`, which means `newton` can't work with it.

Solution: allow explicit promotion of these values. A standard way to do that is `realToFrac`.

```
impEuler :: (Double -> Forward Double -> Forward Double) -> (Double,Double) -> Double
impEuler f (x, y) newx = newy
 where newy = newton fDisc y 1e-3
       fDisc :: Forward Double -> Forward Double
       fDisc yUnknown = yUnknown - realToFrac y + realToFrac (newx - x) * f x yUnknown
```

Note that I had to curry the function `f`, so it takes the time argument separately, as a constant, before the solution variable.

Comment: If you remove the type signature for `fDisc`, lift it out, or enable `ScopedTypeVariables`, you can give `impEuler` the more general type `(Real p, Real q, Fractional q) => ((p, Forward q) -> Forward q) -> (p, q) -> p -> q`.